# Throw and display error message as an associative array

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

So I have been working on a project for a while, and I need to display error messages using sweetalerts, for this I need three things, the type of error which will just set the color of the alert, the title of the error, and the message.

```
    throw ValidationException::withMessages(
                    'error' => [
                    'title' => 'error',
                    'type' => 'warning',
                    'text' => 'error_message'
            ]);
```

The problem is that I don't know how I can display this in a blade template when using the @error directive in my javascript

```
         @error('error')
            $(document).Toasts('create', {
                title: "{!! $message['title'] !!}!",
                class: "bg-{!! $message['type'] !!}",
                autohide: true,
                delay: 5000,
                body: "{!! $message['text'] !!}",
                animationSpeed: 100,
                accordion: true,
                expandSidebar: false
            })
         @enderror
```

This is what I have so far, however It doesn't really work, I would like to know how to pull off this task since it is kind of urgent.

Edit: For clarification, after the error is thrown and the view is rendered I get an error "Cannot access offset of type string on string"

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't really work"? Are there any console errors, how does the rendered JS statement look like?

Comment: Sorry for a quick edit, but I had editted the code just a tad, in any case though, the error message reads 'Cannot access offset of type string on string'

Comment: So the laravel error page is displayed? If so, try adding [] around the data passed into `withMessages()`

Comment: So if I understood correctly what would be in withMessages() would be something along the lines of [ 'error' => [...] ], if that's the case I already tried that to the same result unfortunately

Comment: I will ask you again, is the laravel error page showing, if so, then there is a log file in storage that should point you to the exact problem in your code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a while of searching I came across a couple of methods that helped me solve the issue, it seems that Throw doesn't accept arrays, which is a shame, however after looking into json_encode() I managed to come up with a solution

```
'error' => json_encode([
                'title' => 'error_title',
                'type' => 'warning',
                'text' => 'error_message'
            ])
```

This will then give you a $message string containing all of the data in JSON format, with this you go to your javascript and decode it to put it on an object like so:

```
const message = JSON.parse('{!! $message !!}')
```

And then to access the properties of that object you just do the usual, so

```
message.title
```

Is gonna be equivalent to a hypothetical

```
$message['title']
```